# MySQL PDO connection php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to do a simple pdo connection using the following:

test.php:

```
require 'config.php'

try {
    $dox_db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $config['DB_USER'], $config['DB_PW']);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

and config.php:

```
$config = array(
    'DB_USER' => 'root',
    'DB_PW' => 'password'
);
```

Due to the fact that when I put in wrong information, the page does not display an exception, I'm lead to believe that the database must not be connecting. I have verified that the db service & server is up. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: At top of your script add error_reporting(E_ALL); what you see?

Comment: I added error_reporting(E_ALL); at the top of the script. The php doc is still blank, even though the name of the database is incorrect and exception message appear

Comment: If you don't have exception, how do you know that the DB is not connected? How do you try to access your data?

Comment: in my connection string i reference (new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test') and i do not have a database named 'test' in my sql server

Comment: Try adding double quotes for those $config

Comment: The error is not in connection. It's too simple to make a mistake here.

Comment: hello, I just noticed that this only happens when I'm running on .NET environment (using Microsoft WebMatrix). I see that in the web.config file the connection is already referenced. Does anyone know how to query when the connection string is in the web.config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If test database doesn't exist, must appear something like that on page;

> ERROR: SQLSTATE[42000] [1049] Unknown database 'test'

And I didn't understand how it's work

```
require 'config.php'
```

Can you try this

```
require 'config.php';

try {
    $dox_db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $config['DB_USER'], $config['DB_PW']);
    var_dump($dox_db);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<?php
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set("display_errors", 1);
?>
```

on top of test.php and check what errors it showing?